# Unknown return type for a C function

Tags: c, function, return-type

I am writing a library for C, and one function can return either a string (`char *`), an integer or a double. Next to that, the length of the string is unknown. I really don't know how to deal with this problem. I thought about using pointers as arguments to the function but that is really messy.

Can anyone give me a solution, and maybe some short sample code? Thanks.

---

#### Edit

What about a void pointer as return type, and a pointer to the size of the returned value as argument:

```
void* func(int x, int y, int *size) { ... }
/* or */
void* func(int x, int y, int &size) { ... }
/* always confused about them ): */
```

?

Comment: You can accomplish this with a union or in other ways, but first ask yourself if you *really* need to do this.  Is there some other way you could solve the underlying problem?  If no, why not?

Comment: It has to do with key-value stuff. Keys are always strings and values can be of any type.

Comment: Oh, of course! The programmer knows the type of the value. That will be different functions then.

Comment: How do you intend to actually use the function?  can you design things to have 3 functions (one for each return type) instead?  Aside from the problem of returning different types, how do you plan to manage the lifetime of the returned string (who's going to be responsible for freeing the memory used by the string)?

Comment: The second example you give is not valid C. References are from C++.

Comment: Regarding the example code in your edit, use `int *`.  The `int &` form is C++.  If you are going to return data in an argument like that, then return *all* of your data via argument.  Returning part by return value and part by argument can be more confusing.

Answer (score 8):

If a function can return multiple types, I would not recommend using a union (not alone, at least).  Your function needs to return two pieces of information:  the result, and the type of the result.  You might get the best mileage out of using a structure like this one:

```
enum return_val_type {STRING, INT, DOUBLE};
struct return_val {
    enum return_val_type return_type;
    union {
        char*  s;
        int    i;
        double d;
    };
};
```

That way, the caller can check the value of `return_type` and determine how they need to interpret the data (that is, which union field to use).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like really bad design, but if you feel that you have to do this for some reason then you could use a union to return different types.

Comment: I like the union idea. Returning unions as function values is supported in modern C's, isn't it?

Comment: Does a union really help?  How does the caller know which union field to access?

Comment: @bta: if you can't infer the return type from context (which would be a little weird, but we already know this is a bad design) then you could always embed the union in a struct with an enum field which signifies the valid type within the union.

Comment: @Carl: yes, I think only the original K&R C lacked this capability - everything from C89 onwards allows structs and unions to be returned by functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to redesign your function, or have multiple versions based on type.

Just think about it - how would the compiler be able to handle it? Assuming the implementation is in a separate .c file, the function is a black box to the compiler, so it has no idea what to expect.

You could either one version of the function for each type, or return a pointer, or take a pointer as an argument and store the value in there (which could be unsafe if the size of your result is unknown).